# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'employerCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one arguments undefined but i don't understand why.
If I put my controller in app.js folder but everything works as I intend to create a good structure nothing works.

structure:

```
index
  app
     app.js
  components
     home
         views
              job_offers.html
         controller
              employer_controller.js
```

My controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.employerCtrl', []);

app.controller("employerCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.title = "Fronteend Software Engineer";
    $scope.company = "Bee Engineering";
    $scope.city = "Lisbon";
    $scope.schedule = "Full-time";
    $scope.date = "17-10-2016";
    console.log($scope.city,$scope.title);

}]);
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/",{
            templateUrl: "app/components/home/views/job_offers.html",
            controller: "employerCtrl"
        })
        .when("/job" , {
            templateUrl: "app/components/job/views/job.html",
            controller: "job"
        })
        .when("/formation" , {
            templateUrl: "app/components/formation/views/formation.html",
            controller: "formation"
        }) 
        .when("/news" , {
            templateUrl: "app/components/news/views/news.html",
            controller: "news"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        })
});
```

html

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp" >


<!-- About Section -->
<section id="slide" class="about-section" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row content" ng-view>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to declare the module for the controller again,

```
//remove this line
var app = angular.module('myApp.employerCtrl', []);

app.controller("employerCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.title = "Fronteend Software Engineer";
    $scope.company = "Bee Engineering";
    $scope.city = "Lisbon";
    $scope.schedule = "Full-time";
    $scope.date = "17-10-2016";
    console.log($scope.city,$scope.title);

}]);
```

Comment: work :) but is strange because he had asked me to declare. Thanks

Comment: who asked to declare?

Comment: my console he said had not made that's why I added. Probably confuse the error and was with another.